# sessions and cookies storage

Tags: reactjs, node.js

history.ts:649 Use of history.pushState in a trivial session history context, which maintains only one session history entry, is treated as history.replaceState.

After logging in using the application I'm building with react and node js, I deleted the cookie stored and I tried to log in again but it wasn't storing any cookie